# MySQL - Split results of count function into columns derived from a separate column

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, pivot, count

The title seems a bit confusing, but I am struggling to put down what I need this query to do so best to explain it. I have 3 tables in my database (Using MySQL Workbench), but for this query I'm just trying to use one.

The table named `service_data` has the following columns:

| Services_ID | Service_Type | Day | Time | Customer_ID(FK) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | SERVICE1 | Mon | 0950 | 1 |
| 1002 | SERVICE2 | Tue | 1032 | 65 |
| 1003 | SERVICE3 | Wed | 0859 | 4 |

The table contains approx. 200 records, my aim is to group the timings together, which I have managed to achieve by doing this:

```
select 
  case WHEN (
    Delivery_Time between '08:00:00' 
    and '09:00:00'
  ) then '0800-0900' WHEN (
    Delivery_Time between '09:00:00' 
    and '10:00:00'
  ) then '0900-1000' WHEN (
    Delivery_Time between '10:00:00' 
    and '11:00:00'
  ) then '1000-1100' WHEN (
    Delivery_Time between '11:00:00' 
    and '12:00:00'
  ) then '1100-1200' WHEN (
    Delivery_Time between '12:00:00' 
    and '13:00:00'
  ) then '1200-1300' WHEN (
    Delivery_Time between '13:00:00' 
    and '14:00:00'
  ) then '1300-1400' WHEN (
    Delivery_Time between '14:00:00' 
    and '15:00:00'
  ) then '1400-1500' WHEN (
    Delivery_Time between '15:00:00' 
    and '16:00:00'
  ) then '1500-1600' WHEN (
    Delivery_Time between '16:00:00' 
    and '17:00:00'
  ) then '1600-1700' WHEN (
    Delivery_Time between '17:00:00' 
    and '18:00:00'
  ) then '1700-1800' WHEN (
    Delivery_Time between '18:00:00' 
    and '19:00:00'
  ) then '1800-1900' WHEN (
    Delivery_Time between '19:00:00' 
    and '20:00:00'
  ) then '1900-2000' WHEN (
    Delivery_Time between '20:00:00' 
    and '21:00:00'
  ) then '2000-2100' else 'Outside Opening Hours' end as `Time Period`, 
  count(0) as 'count' 
from 
  service_data 
group by 
  `Time Period` 
order by 
  count desc 
limit 
  20;
```

Which produces the below result:

| TimePeriod | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 1700-1800 | 24 |
| 1500-1600 | 21 |
| 1200-1300 | 19 |
| 1400-1500 | 19 |
| 1800-1900 | 17 |
| 1100-1200 | 17 |
| 1300-1400 | 16 |
| 1600-1700 | 16 |
| 1000-1100 | 16 |
| 1900-2000 | 12 |
| 0800-0900 | 12 |
| 0900-1000 | 11 |

What I am now trying to do is split the count up so that there are 4 columns labelled `SERVICE1`, `SERVICE2`, `SERVICE3` and `SERVICE4` (the values within the `Service_Type` column), so that it looks something like this:

| TimePeriod | SERVICE1 | SERVICE2 | SERVICE3 | SERVICE4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1700-1800 | 6 | 7 | 10 | 1 |
| 1500-1600 | 5 | 9 | 1 | 6 |
| 1200-1300 | 0 | 4 | 2 | 13 |

Is this possible?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is referred as 'pivot', but MySQL knows nothing about it.

Answer (score 0):

'Bug':  Since `BETWEEN` is inclusive, a 10:00 delivery will be in the '0900-1000' bucket.

See the `[pivot]` tag for discussion of how to solve your problem.  Here's a crude attempt:

```
SELECT  CONCAT(hr, "-", hr+1, "00") AS TimePeriod
        SUM(IF(service_type = 'SERVICE1', ct, 0)) AS SERVICE1,
        SUM(IF(service_type = 'SERVICE2', ct, 0)) AS SERVICE2,
        SUM(IF(service_type = 'SERVICE3', ct, 0)) AS SERVICE3,
        SUM(IF(service_type = 'SERVICE4', ct, 0)) AS SERVICE4
    FROM (
        SELECT  HOUR(Delivery_Time) AS hr,
                service_type,
                COUNT(*) as ct
            FROM service_data
            GROUP BY 1,2
         ) AS x
```

Notice that I approached the hours in a different way.

To do "outside", change `CONCAT(hr, "-", hr+1, "00") AS TimePeriod` to

```
IF ( hr BETWEEN 8 AND 20,   -- assuming hours are 08:00 to 20:59
     CONCAT(hr, "-", hr+1, "00"),
     'Outside Opening Hours' )  AS TimePeriod
```